# Android: onKeyUp and onKeyDown?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble understanding onKeyUp and onKeyDown...
I have an app that resembles a DialPad with imagebuttons rendered. Everytime a button is clicked a sound plays, for instance if imagebutton 0 is clicked a sound saying "zero" will be played and during the click the imagebutton background is changed.
Here's an example of how the imagebutton works when its clicked thru the screen...

```
private synchronized void playSound(int tone) {
    if(mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();

    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), tone);
    mp.start();
}

private void ButtonClickSound() {
    ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.mamacita_one);
        }
    });
}
```

Now my onKeyDown method looks like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent ev) {

    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
        playSound(R.raw.mamacita_zero);         
        return true;
    }
}
```

The xml for the button looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/green0" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/blue0" /> <!-- default -->
```

My question is how do I implement onKeyUp and let the imagebutton switch background during the click ???

Answer (score 0):

Use ToggleButton instead of Image Button.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

In the source code, you could use isChecked() property of ToggleButton to play sound

change the xml button to

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/greendot"
      android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/reddot" />
</selector>
```